Signing MSI on multiple server
We have a legacy webapp which is hosted on a separate server machine for each customer. (customer1.xyz.com, customer2.xyz.com, etc.) The webapp has an ability to generate MSI file for customers to download and install on their user desktops. If we wanted to sign the MSI's, do we need to get separate certificate for each machine? Or, can we just get one certificate but use the private key to sign the MSI on each machine?
